# css how to put the fixed div to full width in Iphone IOS

Tags: html, css

In a desctop its all okay, but when I watch it at Iphone I see that the fixed div isn't fully displayed at its full width, is there any way to make it displayed at full width?

```
height: 94px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
```

Comment: I don't know what to try, i am just asking

Comment: As an example, try this: `<div style="position:fixed; width:100%; top:30px; left:0px; background:#f4f4f4; padding:30px; border:1px solid gray;">
some content of your choice.
</div>
`. In my ipad, this is working in both vertical and horizontal positions.

Comment: my div is too large to fit in the screen, I've tried your example its still not displayed fully, maybe I should use media queries or use zoom properties, thats because the screen is small and the div is fixed and too large and I can't scroll it, because its fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    @media handheld {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    }
    @media Screen {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 100;
    }
```

That way it knows if it's mobile or desktop! Hope it works...